# How do I update my web app's database when a change is made on QuickBooks Online?

Tags: mysql, web-applications, synchronization, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a web app with a MySQL database we maintain in the cloud that we are trying to integrate with our QuickBooks Online account. We want to sync data between or web app's database and QuickBooks online, such as customer names and addresses. If they update their address in or web app, it's easy to then update it in QuickBooks online using the QuickBooks Online API. However, if they tell us their new address over the phone and we change it directly in QuickBooks online, we have no idea how to have that trigger something so that it automatically updates our MySQL web app. How do we go about doing this or learning about this process?

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Intuit/QuickBooks has an API that's specifically geared towards this use-case. From the docs:

> The change data capture (CDC) operation returns a list of entities that have changed since a specified time. This operation is for an app that periodically polls Data Services and then refreshes its local copy of entity data.

Docs are here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/change_data_capture

Basically you make an OAuth signed HTTP `GET` request like this:

- https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1234/cdc?entities=Class,Item,Invoice&changedSince=2012-07-20T22:25:51-07:00

And you get back a list of objects that have changed since the given date/time.

Your application can remember the last time you called this, and periodically call this API to get things that have changed since the last time you called it.

You get back something like this:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-04-03T10:36:19.393Z">
   <CDCResponse>
    <QueryResponse>
        <Customer>...
        </Customer>
        <Customer>...
        </Customer>
    </QueryResponse>
    <QueryResponse>
        <Invoice>...
        </Invoice>
        <Invoice>...
        </Invoice>
    </QueryResponse>
    </CDCResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```